# MVC4 Login Option

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am a junior C# developer. My question is basically surrounding what options I have for utilizing logins and such for an MVC4 application.

Whilst studying I learnt how to use the standard MVC3 login/account set up, memberships/roles and such, basically the same as what you see in a demo MVC3 project provided in Visual Studio 2010, which I have used previously for personal ideas.

I now however want to do the same, using the MVC4 approach. It seems as though things have changed a bit from MVC3 to MVC4, so I was hoping someone might be able to let me know if using the MVC4 Internet Application template approach is a good idea, or if there is a better way to go about utilizing logins/accounts/roles.

Any help is much appreciated, cheers,

 - Adam

Comment: I think the membership provider in both mvc3 and mvc4 are identical.